# Adding two DataScroller to one DataTable

Tags: jsf, facelets, myfaces, tomahawk

I would like to add two DataScroller to one DataTable (on the top and on the bottom of the page). One DataScroller works so far. This one is binded to my backbean where the first page is chosen (scroller.getUIData().setFirst(0);)

Now I tried to add the second DataScroller whích is just a copy of the first one with a new id. It seems to be a problem if you are binding two DataScrollers to the same backbean. So I have to delete the binding of the second DataScroller.

Is this okay? Isn't there any other solution? Why can't I just use two equal DataScroller for ione table?

Thanks.

Comment: If I just don't use binding again will the two DataScroller always be synchronized?

Comment: The "DataScroller" isn't recognizable as part of standard JSF. Please mention and tag the specific component library used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like binding just one of the DataScroller works fine. Both scrollers are synchronized and work without any problem.